# FFMPEG: Output tiles onto a black background

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command, which converts a video and also generates a 10x9
tileset. Currently it gets the longer side and either generate a 90px wide or
45px tall tiles. My problem is that each tile has to be 90x45 large, so in
essence what I need is a properly resized and centered tile inside a black
bounding box. How can I achieve this?

The resulting tile

[image: result]

What I would like to achieve

[image: like]

Actual command line

```sh
ffmpeg -i K/vertical.mp4 .... vertical.out.mp4
ffmpeg -i K/vertical.mp4 -an -vsync vfr \
-vf select="isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,2)",scale="'if(gt(iw,ih),90,-1)':'if(gt(iw,ih),-1,45)'",tile="10x9" \
-qscale:v 3 './f/f%03d.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maintaining Aspect Ratio Using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/q/423682/maintaining)

```sh
ffmpeg -i infile.jpg -vf 'pad=90:ih:(ow-iw)/2' outfile.jpg
```

Comment: Padding looks like the thing I need, I'm tryin gettin the output I want.